# Find max of odd positions of a vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector, max, min

I am trying to find the max element of the odd (or even) positions of a vector in C++.

For example using the code below i can find the max elements of the vector `timer_table`:

```
timer_table[ii]= *std::max_element(timer_table.begin(), timer_table.end());
```

Is there any way to get the max of the odd positions of the vector? For instance if `timer_table = {1, 22, 6, 3, 100, 2}`, I want to get 22 or 100 (for even or odd).

Comment: Perhaps a `for` loop?

Comment: Sounds like a very artificial problem. Why not split the values into two vectors in the first place?

Comment: @AmiTavory: If you want to use library, you may use some *range* library  and use adaptator like [strided](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/strided.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complexity of `max_element()` is O(n), so you could write an O(n) `for` loop by yourself. Use the appropriate condition while increasing the index variable (`i+=2`) with `i=0` for even indices and `i=1` initialization for odd indices.

Although this is very easy, I'm adding the code for the sake of completeness.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "vector"
using namespace std;

vector <int> :: iterator odd_max (vector <int> &x)
{
    vector <int> :: iterator it = x.begin() + 1;
    for (vector <int> :: iterator i = it + 2; i < x.end(); i+=2)
        if (*i > *it) it = i;
    return it;
}

vector <int> :: iterator even_max (vector <int> &x)
{
    vector <int> :: iterator it = x.begin();
    for (vector <int> :: iterator i = it + 2; i < x.end(); i+=2)
        if (*i > *it) it = i;
    return it;
}


int main()
{
    vector <int> timer_table = {1, 22, 6, 3, 100, 2};
    cout << *odd_max(timer_table) << '\n';
    cout << *even_max(timer_table) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: thanks man! it helped a lot... for the sake of completeness ;-)

Comment: @user1971010 If it helped, you should upvote it, no?

Comment: You should pass the vectors by `const &` or at least `&` to avoid making copies.

Comment: could you explain more about the `const &` please?

Comment: `const` is used if no changes to the parameters are intended. however, using `const` here would not be the best idea, as the iterator would have to be made `const` and therefore the return iterator would also have to be `const`. This can solved, but its not worth the trouble, I think. `&` is used to pass a parameter by reference. This bypasses the unnecessary copying of the parameter. Also, you don't lose reputation by upvoting :p

Answer (score 0):

```
int max_even = timer_table[0];
int max_odd = timer_table[1];
bool even = true;
for( int v : timer_table )
{
    if( even ) {
    if( v > max_even )
        max_even = v;
    } else {
    if( v > max_odd )
        max_odd = v;
    }
    even = ! even;
}
std::cout << "max even " << max_even << " max odd " << max_odd << std::endl;
```

Runnin at [cpp.sh/7yvcx](http://cpp.sh/7yvcx)

Comment: any way to make it run on C++98?

Comment: Change the for loop to explicitly use a vector iterator.